# Jquery ajax is not able to send data to mvc3 controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am working with MVC3. I have a javascript function which makes an ajax call to mvc3 controller action. When i send null in the data, it calls the controller action. but when I try to send location in data it gives javascript error i.e. 'this is not defined'.

```
function getPictureContent(location)
{
    var pictures = getLocationPictures(location);
    var content = "<div id=markerpictures></div>";  

    return content;
}

function getLocationPictures(location) {
var pics;
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "/Home/GetLocationPictures",
    data : {'location' : location},
    contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType : 'json',
    async : false,
    success : function (data) {         
                 pics = data;
    }        
});

return pics;    
}
```

Here is the controller action:

```
public JsonResult GetLocationPictures(string location)
{
    List<string> pictures = new List<string>();
    return Json(pictures);
}
```

Comment: What are you sending in as `location`? From your error it looks like you're sending in an object that is not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.. Location should be string.Be sure that will string.

```
function getLocationPictures(location) {
var pics;
$.ajax({
type : "POST",
url : "/Home/GetLocationPictures",
data : JSON.stringify({'location' : location}),
contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType : 'json',
async : false,
success : function (data) {         
             pics = data;
}        
});
```